# Wordpress export data from database to csv using $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am stuck with this problem, i have a code to insert the data to database, and query it all at the wordpress page. then i want to export it in csv, but i dont know how to do it. i have codes found on internet but not working. i dont know why, please check my codes. this is my codes..

```
 global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST["Export"])){
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM backend_member', ARRAY_A);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=EXPORT_' . $date . '.csv');

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if ($row) {
            exportCsv(array_keys($row));
        }}
    while ($row) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
                exportCsv($row);
        }}
    function exportCsv($rows) {
        $separator = '';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo $separator . $row;
            $separator = ',';
        }
        echo "\r\n";
    }
}

<div><form class="form-horizontal" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="upload_excel">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><input class="btn btn-success" name="Export" type="submit" value="export to excel" /></div>
</div>
</form></div>
```

When i click export. i have an error.

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://www.rimelig-skat.dk/din-admin/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Comment: where did you put your code?

Comment: i put the code at the same page.

Comment: @BhumiShah please help me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is updated code:

```
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST["Export"])){
    $filename = 'test';
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM     tp_users', ARRAY_A);
    fputcsv( $output, array('ID', 'Title', ' Date'));
    foreach ( $result as $key => $value ) {
        $modified_values = array(
                        $value['ID'],
                        $value['user_login'],
                        $value['user_email']
        );
        fputcsv( $output, $modified_values );
    }
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    // header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . " " . $date . ".csv\";" );
    // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lunchbox_orders.csv');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");exit;
}
```

HTML

```
<div><form class="form-horizontal" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="upload_excel">
```

This code is perfectly working fine in my wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is same Page? or i need to add that code on function.php? i will try this one.

Comment: you need to add  action in functions.php

Comment: I am using child theme on wordpress , what function.php need to update??

Comment: You can put it on child function.php but Is this button in admin panel?

Comment: what do you mean? i dont get it :(

Comment: You export button form is in admin or front side

Comment: on front side sir.  http://www.rimelig-skat.dk/din-admin/ i want to export to csv that table. please check the website sir. thank you.

Comment: Yes, thank you sir.. i am using Post Snippets plugin to insert my php code.

Comment: Updated!!. Just put code in same file and change fields as per your table

Comment: Can you show me you output sir? i got this output http://prntscr.com/gguf51

Comment: Have you added php on top of page?

Comment: where do i make mistakes sir?

Comment: I already put on the header. why there are many text? http://prntscr.com/ggukzj i dont know what to do. :(

Comment: because you post code is not on top of everything. before you php code, there is css and other code.

Comment: what is the best todo sir? how do i overpass them? how do i input into top? thanks

Comment: Thank you sir, I already fix.i put my php on header.php file.. thank you so much for your help.. sorry i cant vote up you.. but thank you so much.